# Add remove div on click on next and Previous

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hide, show

I have multiple DIVs that need to be hidden and show only one div at a time. Using `OnClick` event on `Next` and `Previous`, I want the next div or Previous div to show with slide effect.

```
<div id="box_element_1">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_2">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_3">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_4">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_5">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_6">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_7">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_8">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_9">
Content Show Here
</div>

<div id="box_element_10">
Content Show Here
</div>

<a href="#">Next</a>
<a href="#">Previous</a>
```

Comment: what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/). No one will write code for you. Learn from the link given achieve your goal. :-)

Comment: Please check this below Code

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery .show() and .hide() with slideUp() on your click events:

```
    $('#divs').not('[id=box_element_'+index+']').hide();
    $('#box_element_'+index).show().delay(500).slideUp(1000);
```